# Parse VB code for comments

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'making a small NodeJS app that can run against a large codebase to detect certain words within the code comments.  I'm having trouble reliably matching the comment syntax for `*.vb` files that use a single quote `'` to being a comment.

Here's the regex I have so far, which is imperfect: `^(?:[^"]+)'(.+)$`

Test page: https://regex101.com/r/V0CHV2/4

The tricky part is not matching single quotes within a string.  Here's my test case.

```vb
''' <summary>
''' Runs the auth check.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="authToken">The auth token.</param>
Public Shared Sub AuthCheck(ByVal authToken As AuthToken)
  'This is a "comment" - oh yeah
  If Not authToken.Equals(foo, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then 'else
    Throw New Exception("don't count this as a comment!") 'comment here
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with this variant:

```
^(?:(?:"(?:\\"|[^"])*")|[^"'])*\s*'+\s*(.*)
```

Note that writing parsers for this sort of stuff using purely regular expressions can be difficult. This seems to [extract the content](https://regex101.com/r/V0CHV2/5) properly.

This accounts for situations like this:

```
func("This is \"Bob's\" string") ''' Comment!
```

It's important to not get tripped up on things like `\"` where that's actually not the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

I would give a shot with `\s*'[^"\n]*("[^"\n]*"[^"\n]*)*$`. You can see the regex on [regex101.com with your sample](https://regex101.com/r/t9kjiE/1)

Comment: That's better but still inadequate.

Comment: I've been to this rodeo before, and it's a wild one. Yours is pretty close, though!